# How to add a column more to a list output

Tags: r, datatable, model, double

I'm trying obtaing some tables from this code

```
models_list_1 <- data_long %>%
  group_by(signals) %>%
  do(fit = lmerTest::lmer(value ~ COND*SES + (1 |ID), data = .)) %>% 
  pull(fit) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) summary(x) %>% coefficients()) %>% 
  map( ~ .x %>% 
         broom::tidy() %>% pull(x))
```

When I explore through it, I can see its content like this

[image]

That actually exclude the first column of the output

[image]

And counting 5 instead than six coulmns. Is there any procedure to fix it? I do not know whether it could be possible to convert the double element into atibble or something else.

Here below the data

```
> dput(head(data_long, 350))
structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06"), GR = c("RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP"), SES = c("L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L"), COND = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC"), signals = c("P3(400-450).FCz", 
"P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz"), value = c(-13.733750856001, 
-9.75024624896264, 2.65626156135631, -11.2145748677083, -8.14861856277773, 
3.4315211013568, -7.774797181711, -5.0379636708446, 4.67200616533014, 
-0.397250087672501, 2.91913936481813, 8.38141924882334, 9.61455213192824, 
-11.0706676917232, -8.42427447113084, 3.37360619561252, -13.9481657323772, 
-11.7645758007163, -1.55179922542943, -8.40872060176111, -6.36865552801825, 
1.75888442936359, 1.01519755373062, 1.85489998202138, 4.88842858528025, 
7.21299011910717, -8.4719202003519, -5.61886494275071, 5.4043480635031, 
-12.0047623683783, -9.16726244915301, 1.13509020104859, -7.03235376576925, 
-4.54670193355435, 2.49276476951357, -1.17300033366376, 0.694393606954545, 
5.0594399581601, 6.1861244061312, -5.04318152659785, 0.73152672768007, 
19.5226358864568, -4.24372139176794, 0.918751423320568, 16.3120391015512, 
-0.65010821749741, 4.05493850786385, 13.8997702651793, 0.663115370014327, 
3.95694572160701, 3.88831364571248, 6.46723813995257, -6.25375875400145, 
1.11453058993788, 18.5017390789352, -7.38414465678688, -0.674372568935879, 
14.1694182774958, -3.24350263682843, 2.67516303169366, 13.2135623121441, 
-1.72160165493474, 2.36649557381131, 5.83201076558185, 7.25962635499353, 
-7.0474968134059, -2.25104720773472, 11.7844254386573, -6.61221718491095, 
-2.47425935490564, 9.04781409226351, -2.84832379590422, 1.02479302810681, 
9.51479768101391, 0.0540027107377267, 2.71292196345657, 3.65113189260335, 
7.92952342178602, -11.6312151716924, -5.16524399006139, 11.8802266972569, 
-11.7785042972793, -5.96429031525769, 8.23981597718437, -5.67295796971287, 
-0.774461731301161, 9.99385579756163, -0.198736254963744, 2.96437294922766, 
6.28027312932027, 7.91468942320841, -11.1438413285935, -5.53112490175437, 
12.1053426662461, -9.14927207125904, -5.10918437158799, 9.51261484648731, 
-4.3918290080777, -0.650009462761383, 11.1212652173052, -3.16101041766438, 
-2.12913230708907, 5.24535230966772, 9.94838815736199, -3.99591470944713, 
0.621502123415388, 12.955441582096, -7.58190508537766, -2.81732229625975, 
9.42367409925817, -2.96652960658775, 1.14010250644923, 10.6989716871958, 
0.895992279831378, 2.94619035115619, 7.68162285335806, 10.2186482048953, 
8.71618523084192, 10.0972150696175, 13.9718285231429, 14.2438131545118, 
18.1277616996079, 20.6284861844249, 12.5228696634748, 15.0856583318757, 
15.4011622649207, 9.21248347391488, 10.0673617448764, 8.55827491190151, 
5.76901446016799, 3.1567164130045, 3.29671672118792, 6.37710361710325, 
10.3728637305957, 14.0324104861749, 17.1194345279475, 10.1688421767607, 
12.7218688256241, 13.5845965959489, 4.2029104966206, 5.28032844958354, 
4.37390045274906, 1.63411653734436, 0.11779005903818, 0.527314779744752, 
3.52040283490143, 4.71555467505934, 7.88901307601169, 9.74981375898379, 
4.94891653050796, 7.04929483656524, 7.62145250862908, 5.29260474692784, 
5.76317883868431, 4.27567967018154, 2.14044069620066, 6.2230923800622, 
7.48013969467974, 13.9681839573434, 8.16263381384371, 10.9263261999576, 
15.5578942384162, 8.29234474523583, 9.71944484568732, 12.4214977980377, 
4.43538787409554, 4.54790063971537, 6.04702803069286, 4.09091078261671, 
0.545039723311392, 2.24297008138028, 8.64955428897889, 2.54754270788021, 
5.40070389371842, 10.3425870381822, 2.89989209310052, 5.19815917760722, 
8.94731174966949, 1.28346027317076, 2.16569592764593, 5.29458007289059, 
5.32593378182311, -0.383605036065646, -0.0523505792147314, 2.80847380898547, 
-1.01463338713448, 0.139150314055044, 3.41932708826405, 1.69916872833203, 
2.20513206952329, 4.10953557761617, 1.17003451023205, 1.33824716938448, 
1.21234812875355, -0.0587064331536407, -2.10936383457265, 0.0473343786951428, 
10.1644392609445, -6.4216236476269, -4.61042211238648, 4.05274207265641, 
-1.13332962482291, -0.20305866581144, 5.80373742668179, 3.21881665778703, 
2.58426832963409, 6.30887598671621, 6.86490468078958, 1.81064934015995, 
2.78240093455642, 13.2788201390174, -4.08374576377548, -3.5562551128714, 
3.767844291789, 0.649857280429136, 1.01053594416015, 5.74639215930458, 
5.92604591551597, 5.077230852852, 5.9614279900414, 5.26280996552585, 
0.754416368133019, 2.60057993978525, 10.5077997492971, -8.46742290376216, 
-6.85651693740331, 0.326110657534835, -4.43684347222634, -2.96241685765962, 
1.48762660613099, -2.75555354427229, -1.59699177169018, -0.609381826740468, 
0.981300734684586, -1.2371236814317, 1.4302038359579, 13.4030666728381, 
-6.30908300837476, -2.17237957159954, 6.65839865279684, -2.31574543509226, 
1.26480036715092, 6.04018553841336, 2.18006640865321, 6.61872855398538, 
3.66646157996528, 5.0384350436334, -2.76852389876276, -0.650797837853182, 
4.74014346829081, -6.72661142802369, -6.18867237684241, 1.17003883692158, 
-2.73359549382074, -2.00512841997728, 1.9050381096835, -0.225533814334514, 
-1.21696526578647, 0.240956222277802, 0.361670119961531, 5.54144355778122, 
7.81248993867768, 11.9003140352528, -3.32736490042247, -1.77938930999718, 
5.40630013085777, -0.38736451456005, -0.423105565152366, 6.37211228749408, 
0.986467266459687, -0.507207892673482, 1.15053325116554, 0.393791410918138, 
-0.314155675382471, 2.23100741241039, 15.0981004360619, -4.01515836011381, 
-1.43557366487622, 5.06332653216481, 0.159183652691071, 1.51403741206392, 
3.7899021820967, 3.11042068112836, 3.44844607014521, 1.08242973465635, 
1.07455889922813, 0.238885648959708, 3.96990710862955, 15.4046229884164, 
-6.60165385653499, -3.14872157912645, 5.02619159395405, -1.78361184935376, 
0.25571835554024, 4.59413830322224, 2.27800090558473, 3.02403433835637, 
2.99896314000211, 1.65917850515029, 5.03749946898385, 7.75899775608441, 
16.671036999147, -2.02861964460179, 0.160393685024631, 9.07903916629231, 
1.97377908783621, 3.76051565494304, 8.52123662617732, 3.83846437952292, 
4.7045767546583, 5.36085942954182, 3.22422743232682, 0.515492206557273, 
0.204266730001714, 6.24616732032065, 5.8666814083179, 6.04784652351361, 
11.3067210486656, 6.83112977894818, 6.84424120299137, 11.0326576935158, 
2.11741401205978, 1.31359485387859, 2.79229514887897, 4.15964501337974, 
-3.44241289723487, -3.87922889171612, 4.78883251402879, 2.33082585113171, 
3.3201189812225, 9.74936883279237, 1.66856860799729, 3.42983447849866, 
8.53328996612415, 2.41324857857743, 3.04464581710327, 5.44503756798021, 
5.35297505953096, -3.60371878191807, -4.52390680893631, 3.10163832479954, 
2.40451234371064, 2.77790257477581, 9.14893956441953, 1.50685192543202, 
1.92879865454881, 7.97978028439358, 2.60828710695631, 2.0247782323911, 
5.10559083807721)), row.names = c(NA, -350L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: @danlooo I've tried opening a new post. I do not know wether the problem was not enough clear before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the `str`ucture, it shows a `matrix` (a `matrix` is a `vector` with some `dim` attributes - row/column).  The column specified by the OP is actually the row names attribute - `dimnames` for the rows.  which is not a column

```
> str(models_list_1[[1]])
 num [1:9, 1:5] 4.172 -1.474 -3.805 1.3 -0.431 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "(Intercept)" "CONDNEG-NOC" "CONDNEU-NOC" "SESR" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "df" "t value" ...
```

If we need to add this as a column, convert to `data.frame`/`tibble` and use `rownames_to_column`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
models_list_2 <- map(models_list_1, ~ .x %>%
                 as.data.frame %>%
                 rownames_to_column('categ'))
```

-check the `str` and output of the first element

```
> models_list_2[[1]]
             categ   Estimate Std. Error        df    t value  Pr(>|t|)
1      (Intercept)  4.1722193   2.849113  6.070733  1.4643922 0.1928657
2      CONDNEG-NOC -1.4738234   2.477523 15.075875 -0.5948777 0.5607485
3      CONDNEU-NOC -3.8049756   2.477523 15.075875 -1.5357982 0.1453065
4             SESR  1.2995553   2.728496 15.285616  0.4762900 0.6406044
5             SESV -0.4311587   3.130553 15.329735 -0.1377260 0.8922497
6 CONDNEG-NOC:SESR -1.5831733   3.784479 15.075875 -0.4183332 0.6816018
7 CONDNEU-NOC:SESR -0.2724791   3.784479 15.075875 -0.0719991 0.9435491
8 CONDNEG-NOC:SESV  0.9068900   4.291196 15.075875  0.2113373 0.8354543
9 CONDNEU-NOC:SESV  5.8854969   4.291196 15.075875  1.3715283 0.1902793
> str(models_list_2[[1]])
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ categ     : chr  "(Intercept)" "CONDNEG-NOC" "CONDNEU-NOC" "SESR" ...
 $ Estimate  : num  4.172 -1.474 -3.805 1.3 -0.431 ...
 $ Std. Error: num  2.85 2.48 2.48 2.73 3.13 ...
 $ df        : num  6.07 15.08 15.08 15.29 15.33 ...
 $ t value   : num  1.464 -0.595 -1.536 0.476 -0.138 ...
 $ Pr(>|t|)  : num  0.193 0.561 0.145 0.641 0.892 ...
```

Comment: Hi @akrun here the problem is always the same to attrbute the proper name to table. Will `set_caption(caption = sprintf('Statistics of %s', first(.x$signals)` work as yesterday?

Comment: @mały_statystyczny This one doesn't have the `signals` column as per your data i..e `models_list_2`

Comment: @mały_statystyczny you may need from the original data, i.e. `map2(models_list_2, data_long %>% group_split(signals), ~ ... %>% set_caption(caption = sprintf('Statistics of %s', first(.y$signals))`

Comment: Ok. Do you thin k it is possible to come up with something to add them?

Comment: @mały_statystyczny please check the `map2` comment above. the other parts  (`...`) will be the `flextable` code as in your other post

Comment: if you do not mind I would ike to aks you to showing the extended command. I didn't get wether I to run on the new object you have  created or not

Comment: I meant this `out <- map2(models_list_2, data_long %>% group_split(signals), ~ flextable(.x) %>%
colformat_double(digits = 2) %>% 
  theme_box() %>% 
  valign(valign = "center") %>% autofit() %>% 
  set_caption(caption = sprintf('Statistics of %s', first(.y$signals))))`

Comment: Ok. Thanks I do not want to bother you, if you could have some hints with my last problem of plotting graphs together or someother elese to ask to...